# Chart.js not showing in my view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I have an app running with angular.js and one of my view should load an chart. I'm using chart.js for it, but for some reason it's not working and no error is shown on my console. 
Here is my function that creates the chart:

```
$scope.writeBatteryChart = function(){
        console.log("Function was called");
        var data = {
            labels: ["10:30am", "11:00am", "11:30am", "12:00pm", "12:30pm", "01:00pm", "01:30pm"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Battery",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                }
            ]
        };

        var options = {
            responsive: true,
            bezierCurve : false
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);

    }
```

Here's the HTML where the chart should appear:

```
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel panel-info">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Battery <i class="fi-battery-half"></i></h3>
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <canvas id="myChart" height="300"></canvas>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">

                    </div>
                </div>
```

and I'm also loading the latest version of the Chart.js:

```
    <!--Chart plugin -->
    <script src="bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

One thing that I noticed is that the canvas is being rendered with 0 dimensions:

[image: 0 dimensions on the canvas]

Does someone can see where I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem: I was calling the function before the canvas be loaded on the view, so I used a `setTimeout()` to call the `writeBatteryChart()` with a delay in order to wait the canvas be rendered.

Comment: I had a similar issue when trying to load data before ajax call finished, so I made ajax call first and set onSuccess callback draw the chart, related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894952/draw-a-chart-js-with-ajax-data-and-responsive-a-few-problems-and-questions

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your rendered things inside of canvas. Hope it will help [Link](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)