# How can I make a piechart chart for each row that the database query returns to me?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 or more columns and I have to perform calculation using all columns. And for each row I have to show Pie chart next to that. Creating Pie -chart for suppose 10 rows based on if-else calculation. If anyone can help! Thanks. I'm work in php.

I already made a pie chart as shown in the code below, but I don't know how to create them dynamically.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
                  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                  function drawChart() {

                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                      ['Total de Horas', '8 horas'],
                      <?php foreach ($list as $l) :?>
                      ['Horas faturadas',     <?php echo $l->HorasFaturadas; ?>],
                      ['Horas não faturadas',       <?php echo $l->NaoFaturadas; ?>],
                       <?php endforeach; ?>
                      ['Hours break',120]
                    ]);

                    var options = {
                      title: 'Daily Activities ',
                      slices: {
                        0: { color: 'green' },
                        1: { color: 'red' },
                        2: { color: 'grey'}
                      }
                    };

                    var chart = new 
  google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

                    chart.draw(data, options);
                  }
                </script>  '''
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify more about the dynamic part, if you want data to be shown in real time you will need something like AJAX. AJAX would send data to the controller, the controller to the model, and if the action has success then it will change the data in real time or in a dynamic way.

as for the charts, I would use the popular library [charts.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/)

So, every value that you will calculate with the if-else statements, you will store them in a variable and then show that variable value on the chart.
Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894952/draw-a-chart-js-with-ajax-data-and-responsive-a-few-problems-and-questions) that might help you.